# Keeping an event's changed colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I would like an event to change colour when the user clicks on it.
I am currently using the below code to change the border and text colour and it works fine:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    userClicked (calEvent.start); //used elsewhere, not important to this question
    $(this).css('border-color', 'red'); //shows user what they have clicked
    $(this).css('color', 'red'); //shows user what they have clicked
}//event click
```

I am only showing the user a month view.
This works until the user changes the month using the arrow buttons, once clicked the changed colours are gone and the events have their original colours again.

**I would like to change the colours permanently, unless the user refreshes the page.

How do I keep the event colours the same as what I have changed them too?**

Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to keep track of which items were clicked and render them as such when the month view changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the `calEvent` as first parameter, besides settings the css with jQuery you also have to edit the `borderColor` and `backgroundColor` properties of the event like so:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    userClicked (calEvent.start); //used elsewhere, not important to this question
    $(this).css('border-color', 'red'); //shows user what they have clicked
    $(this).css('color', 'red'); //shows user what they have clicked
    calEvent.backgroundColor = 'red';
    calEvent.borderColor = 'red';
}//event click
```